# Using javascript to build android scrollable tab design

Tags: javascript, android-layout

http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html#scrollable

Has anyone achieved this effect in a web app using JavaScript (or even jQuery)?

Got the pages sliding nicely (obviously that's the easy part), but getting the page titles to animate correctly looks like it could be painful!

May just go with the fixed tab layout but if anyone has any tips or examples, I would be very grateful...

Answer (score 1):

There's a CSS which makes your page look like Android:

- https://github.com/proimage/Android-4-ICS-CSS

There's a more advanced project with some JS:

- http://jaunesarmiento.me/fries/index.html

And this is the way to do page swiping:

- http://stereobit.github.io/dragend/ (also works on the PC)
- http://swipejs.com/ (only works on touch device)
- http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/ (only triggers the event, doen't swipe the page)

With these you can have multiple pages in one HTML file:

- http://handlebarsjs.com/
- https://github.com/janl/mustache.js
- http://underscorejs.org/
- http://embeddedjs.com/
- http://jade-lang.com/
- https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Templates

I'm working myself to combine some of these libs into a usable application. Hope it helps. This is also a note to myself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It's a bit of an old post now so not working on that project any more. Will check out the links anyway. Thanks!